# 12V - 0,67 A USB Wall Charger for iPod Classic

Tags: usb, battery, charging, ipod, ipod-classic

I have a vintage iPod Classic 2004:

[image]

I want charge it with my 10W iPad Pro charger and an USB A -> 30-pin old Apple cable. However, it not charged and started to showing Apple logo in a loop. It ran after connecting it to Mac with USB, so device is working. After looking the details on old brick charger, it is a 12 V and 0,67 A charger. Now, I'm searching a USB charger with these properties.Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Note that if you have the correct cable any Mac will charge it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no USB charger other than USB-C that will supply more than 5V DC.

USB-C (3.1 spec) provides for power delivery and will negotiate up to 20 V. However, the iPod Classic is not USB 3.1 compliant, so it will not negotiate with those chargers.

You need the original Apple charger designed for that device.