# Can I charge my iPhone with a standard USB charger?

Tags: usb, power, iphone

I need to charge my Apple  iPhone, and I don't have an original Apple charger. I have a cable with one end being a male Apple iPhone connector (which fits OK the female socket on my iPhone) and the other end a standard male  USB-A.

Can I use this cable to charge the iPhone from a standard cheap USB charger, e.g., a female socket on my laptop. If yes, should I use a USB 2.0 socket or USB 3.0?

Also I have another cable with a male Apple iPhone connector and a male USB C connector. Can I use it to charge the iPhone from any third-party charger that has a USB-C output? Or my laptop's USB-C socket? That is, won't any of the two devices be damaged -- the iphone or laptop or the USB charger? Also I have a fast-charging charger of my old Huawei phone: It has an USB-A socket I used it with a cable having a male USB-A end (I don't know whether it is 2.0 or 3.0) and a male  USB-C end for the Huawei phone. Both the charger and the cable came with the old Huawei phone -- so my guess is that the charger is designed to negotiate the voltage with the phone similarly as USB-C chargers do. Can I use this charger with that USB-A to Apple cable to (fast?) charge my iPhone?

I realize that the best is to go and buy an original Apple charger, but at this time all shops are closed, and I need my iPhone urgently.

Comment: These things are all standard. If it fits, plug it in. The worst that will happen is that it takes longer to charge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Technically, [You can use any USB charger (or port) to charge your iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402879/119271).

- If your charger supplies less than 1.5A it will charge, but slowly.
- If it supplies 2.5A it will “quick” charge
- If you are using a USB-C PD (Power Delivery)charger with at least 18W, you can [Fast Charge](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208137) where you get up to 50% charge in 30 mins

As far as cables, any *data* cable will do.  It must be a USB-A or USB-C (depending on the charger) to lightning or USB-C (depending on your iPhone model). When you get a cable, make sure it is a quality cable with the USB logo.